# popup window and search contacts

Tags: apex, visualforce, content-search

A window pops up to the Business User .Once clicked the Business User can insert the Email address of the contact would like to merge or delete.
Search all Contact records associated with the Email address (within the same account)

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TestPopup">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:commandButton value="show popup" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="popup" status="status"/>



             <apex:outputPanel id="popup">

                <apex:outputPanel id="popInnerOutputPnl" styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                     <apex:commandButton value="X" title="Close the popup" action="{!closePopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                     </apex:commandButton>
                     <apex:pageblockSection >                         

                         <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                          <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="address"></apex:outputLabel>
                             <apex:inputText id="address" value="{!contact.Email}"/>
                         </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                     </apex:pageblockSection>
                     <apex:commandButton value="Ok" action="{!redirectPopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                     <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!Search}" reRender="popup"/>
                     </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>

             <apex:pageblockTable var="con" value="{!contact}">
              <apex:column value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!con.Email}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!con.Account.Name}"/>
               </apex:pageblockTable>

            </apex:pageBlock>

              </apex:form>

                  <style type="text/css">
.customPopup {
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to tweak so the pop 
                            up displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
                            margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can also add 
                            the height property for a fixed size pop up.*/
    width: 500px;
    top: 20%;
}

.disabledTextBox {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: black;
    cursor: default;
    width: 90px;
    display: table;
    padding: 2px 1px;
    text-align:right;
}   

.closeButton {
    float: right;
}
</style>


</apex:page>
```

=============================

```
public with sharing class TestPopup {

    public Boolean displayPopup {get;set;}
    public list<contact> contact {get;set;}
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public TestPopup(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public void showPopup()
    {

    displayPopup = true;


    }

    public void closePopup() {
        displayPopup = false;

    }

    public PageReference redirectPopup()
    {
    displayPopup = false;
        //Please uncomment below 3 statements and replace YourObjectId
       // PageReference p=new Pagereference('/'+YourObjectId);
       //  p.setRedirect(true);
         return null;

    }

    public PageReference Search(){

    //searched = true;
    string serachstr = 'select id,FirstName,lastName,Email,Account.Name  From Contact where Email Like \''+Email +'%%\' ';
   // contact = [select id,FirstName,lastName From Contact where Email Like : searchstr];
    contact= database.query(serachstr );

        return null;
    }


}
```

> error:Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Email'

Comment: <apex:inputText id="address" value="{!contact.Email}"/>   This is not correct.You have to loopthrough contacts to display it.What do you want to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<apex:inputText id="address" value="{!contact.Email}"/>
```

By this

```
<apex:repeat value="{!contact}" var="con">
    <apex:inputText id="address" value="{!con.Email}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

As contact is a list and you cannot just get contact.Email from a List.
Hope this will Help.

Comment: getting an error ::Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Email'

Comment: changes should be done in controller

Answer (score 0):

According to your question ,I guess you have to pass the entered emailid to search for contacts.Please use the email variable in the input text for the same as below.

```
         <apex:outputPanel id="popup">

            <apex:outputPanel id="popInnerOutputPnl" styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                 <apex:commandButton value="X" title="Close the popup" action="{!closePopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                 </apex:commandButton>
                 <apex:pageblockSection >                         

                     <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                      <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="address"></apex:outputLabel>
                         <apex:inputText id="address" value="{!Email}"/>
                     </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                 </apex:pageblockSection>
                 <apex:commandButton value="Ok" action="{!redirectPopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                 <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!Search}" reRender="popup"/>
                 </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

         <apex:pageblockTable var="con" value="{!contact}">
          <apex:column value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!con.Email}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!con.Account.Name}"/>
           </apex:pageblockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
```

Hope this helps!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TestPopup" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:commandButton value="show popup" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="popup" status="status"/>



              <apex:outputPanel id="popup">

            <apex:outputPanel id="popInnerOutputPnl" styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                 <apex:commandButton value="X" title="Close the popup" action="{!closePopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                 </apex:commandButton>
                 <apex:pageblockSection >                         

                     <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                      <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="address"></apex:outputLabel>
                             <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" label="Input"/>   
                     </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                 </apex:pageblockSection>
                 <!--apex:commandButton value="Ok" action="{!redirectPopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup"-->
                 <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!Search}" styleClass="closeButton" reRender="popup">
                 </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:pageblockTable var="con" value="{!contact}">
          <apex:column value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!con.Email}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!con.Account.Name}"/>
           </apex:pageblockTable>

        </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:pageBlock>


              </apex:form>

                  <style type="text/css">
.customPopup {
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to tweak so the pop 
                            up displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
                            margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can also add 
                            the height property for a fixed size pop up.*/
    width: 500px;
    top: 20%;
}

.disabledTextBox {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: black;
    cursor: default;
    width: 90px;
    display: table;
    padding: 2px 1px;
    text-align:right;
}   

.closeButton {
    float: right;
}
</style>


</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class TestPopup {

    public Boolean displayPopup {get;set;}
    public list<contact> contact {get;set;}
     public string searchstring {get;set;}  
  //  public string Email { get; set; }

    public TestPopup(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public TestPopup (){
   // contact  = new list<Contact>();


    }

    public void showPopup()
    {

    displayPopup = true;


    }

    public void closePopup() {
        displayPopup = false;

    }

    public PageReference redirectPopup()
    {
    displayPopup = false;
        //Please uncomment below 3 statements and replace YourObjectId
       // PageReference p=new Pagereference('/'+YourObjectId);
       //  p.setRedirect(true);
         return null;

    }

    public PageReference Search(){
    displayPopup = false;
    //searched = true;
    string searchquery='select firstName,LastName,id,Account.Name,email from Contact where email like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' Limit 20';  
     contact= Database.query(searchquery);  
     system.debug('record is---->' +contact);
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you fixed and not just a code dump.